# How to call Matlab functions from vb. (Matlab & VB integration)

Tags: vb.net, matlab, dll

I am working with Matlab and VB .Net. I have part of my code in VB, while the other half in Matlab. My main program is in VB but I want to use some of the functions I built in Matlab(for example the m-file functions). Is it possible to import the m-file functions and call them from vb or even through dlls? How do you do it if it's possible?

I know that you can build a Matlab application object in vb and call its internal function by using matlab.execute. Does this allow me to call the functions I built myself?

Also, when I use Matlab execute command, a Matlab command window appear on the task bar. I am OK with the way it is now but if someone knows a way to make it not show that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the directory with `cd` and then execute your function saved in `your_file.m` from there:

```
Dim mObj As Object
Dim res As String
mObj = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")  'create matlab object
res = mObj.Execute("cd c:\your\path")      'change directory
res = mObj.Execute("your_file")            'execute your function
```

I could not find a solution to hide the icon in the taskbar.